# How to set initial value in input field using ref keyword in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, ng-bind

I want to set default value in input field. I was trying to set it in the constructor. But I am unable to do it.

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.favorTitle = "default value";
}
onTextChange = () => {
    console.log(this.favorTitle.value);
}

<input type="text" ref={
    (input) => { 
        this.favorTitle = input;
    }
}
onChange={this.onTextChange} />
```

Comment: Why are you unable to do it?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Can you please update your question with the entire React component. Please also format your code so it appears as monospaced (4 leading spaces). Also..your tag is a little confusing? Is angular also involved somehow?